# how to check system() result

Tags: c++, c, windows, system

How should I check if the system command was run successfully and it didn't return error?
According to [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), there are multiple cases. I couldn't be sure if the following snippet is correct.

```
char buffer[100];
int ret_val;
strcpy(buffer, "copy *.txt ");
strcat(buffer, path);
ret_val = system(buffer);
if(0 != ret_val)
{
  perror("There was an error");
}
else
{
  printf("The command was run successfully.");
}
```

Return Value

If command is NULL and the command interpreter is found, returns a nonzero value. If the command interpreter is not found, returns 0 and sets errno to ENOENT. If command is not NULL, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter. It returns the value 0 only if the command interpreter returns the value 0. A return value of – 1 indicates an error, and errno is set to one of the following values:

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the status of command run by system()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941691/how-to-get-the-status-of-command-run-by-system)

Comment: Never use `system`. It's pretty much impossible to write safe, robust code using it.

Answer (score 1):

To catch all the cases, you also need to check `errno`, like the documentation states:

```
if (ret_val == 0 && errno == 0)
{
  printf("success!\n");
}
```

Make sure you also *clear* `errno` just before calling `system()`.

Comment: it's not really working. I put a file it can not delete and run as you suggested. In the Autos window of Visual Studio 2008, I see "_errno returned 0x00400808". But it goes into this if statement too. :(

Comment: **man 3 system says:** RETURN VALUE
       The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork() failed), and the return
       status  of  the command otherwise.  This latter return status is in the
       format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the  command  will
       be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In  case  /bin/sh could not be executed, the
       exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

Comment: @Pete Wilson and for Windows?

Comment: @mustafa -- Beats me. What did google turn up for you? What did you find on msdn?

Answer (score 0):

Since the argument to `system` is not NULL, you concentrate on that case which is a very simple one: `-1` is the `system` function fails, and otherwise the return code of the actual command.

Comment: I saw that `system` was returning `1` in some cases.

Comment: @mustafa Then it's the actual command (`copy` in your case) that exits with that return code.

Comment: yes, it may be. I created a file it can not delete. on the console it outputs "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." but `system` is still returning `0`