# How to execute local bash script from RabbitMQ?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, rabbitmq

**Greeting all.**

How can achieve next:

1. Publisher (Web client) add a message to the queue.
2. RabbitMQ must execute bash script with an argument from the queue message
3. If the bash script was executed successfully then sent acknowledgment to RabbitMQ
4. After receiving the acknowledgment then RabbitMQ will be executing bash script with an argument from the queue message.
5. Before getting acknowledgment RabbitMQ will be delaying execute the bash script

Is it possible to achive with RabbitMQ?

Could you get me some advice, please?

**Thank very much for your help.**

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `system` C stdlib call to do this. There's some other relevant SO questions that can help you with this. Try help on [this one on executing shell built-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209141/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-built-in-command-with-a-c-function) and [this one on system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941691/how-to-get-the-status-of-command-run-by-system). You can also `man system` and `man execv`.

Parse your queue message, craft a `char *` or `string` object with the command that needs to execute based on the queue message, and then pass it to `system`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941691/how-to-get-the-status-of-command-run-by-system) for help on the return code from `system` if you're not getting it based on the man page.